# Тема части речи

Tags: наречия, части

Учитель по русскому поставил 4 за задание. Помогите разобраться 1-подставка фонетический разбор я разобрал как (пацтафка) а учитель говорит (пацставка) я звук с вообще не слышу. 2 вопрос-темно это какая часть речи наречие?

Answer (score 2):

1. ***Подставка***. Стечение согласных ДСТ. Звук Д оглушается до Т, сочетание ТС дает звук Ц (как в ТСЯ и ТЬСЯ)

Если по науке, то  смычной Т и фрикативный (щелевой) С как раз соответствуют звуку Ц (Т + С = Ц)

Получается — пацтафка, как у вас.

2. ***Темно*** — это наречие.

**Примечание.** Но в старших классах его называют предикативным наречием или словом категории состояния, например: На улице ***темно*** (состояние окружающей среды). И такое предложение, где нет подлежащего, называют безличным. (Но я не уверена, что вы это проходили.)

Слово "темно" может быть еще кратким прилагательным (окно было темно) и обычным обстоятельственным наречием, отнесенным к глаголу (он  выражался всегда темно и неопределенно), но это редкие случаи.

Успехов вам в учебе!

Comment: У автора вопроса еще и буква "в" в слове "подставка" передает звук "ф" в позиции перед глухим согласным "к", поэтому вариант "пацтафка" будет верным

Comment: Да, спасибо за замечание.